# FFMPEG. Using current datetime in the filename. strftime parameter doesn't seem to work

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm connecting to an IP camera and I would like to create a new recording every 60 seconds. Each recording should have a different filename.
I tried with this:

```
ffmpeg -i <url> -y -c:v libx264 -an -f segment -segment_time 60 -strftime 1 "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4"
```

However, this always outputs a filename that looks like:

```
m-H-S.mp4
```

Any ideas what I must be missing?

Thanks

Comment: Try double or triple escaping.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Actually you were right. The problem was because I was running the command from a batch file, so I had to escape the parameters like this: "%%Y-%%m-%%d_%%H-%%M-%%S.mp4". You don't need to do that if you run it directly from the command line.

Comment: @LEM feel free to post an answer to your own question then. Cheers!

Comment: @rogerdpack Thanks! I just did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was because I was running the command from a batch file, so I had to escape the parameters like this: "%%Y-%%m-%%d_%%H-%%M-%%S.mp4". You don't need to do that if you run it directly from the command line.